# Setting values in a numpy arrays indexed by a slice and two boolean arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.arange(100*100).reshape(100,100)
b = np.random.rand(100, 100)
```

I also have a tuple of slices to extract a certain piece of the array:

```
slice_ = (slice(5, 10), slice(5, 10))
```

I then have a set of boolean indices to select a certain part of this slice:

```
indices = b[slice_] > 0.5
```

If I want to set these indices to a different value I can do it easily:

```
a[slice_][indices] = 42
```

However, if I create another set of boolean indices to select a specific part of the indexed array:

```
high_indices = a[slice_][indices] > 700
```

and then try and set the value of the array at these indices:

```
a[slice_][indices][high_indices] = 42 # Doesn't do anything!
```

I thought maybe I needed to AND the two index arrays together, but they are different shape: `indices` has a shape of `(5, 5)` and `high_indices` has a shape of `(12,)`.

I think I've got myself into a terrible muddle here trying to do something relatively simple. How can I index using these two boolean arrays in such a way that I can set the values of the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slicing a numpy array returns a view, but boolean indexing returns a copy of an array. So when you indexed it first time with boolean index in `a[slice_][indices][high_indices]`, you got back a copy, and the value 42 is assigned to a copy and not to the array `a`. You can solve the problem by chaining the boolean index:

```
a[slice_][(a[slice_] > 700) & (b[slice_] > 0.5)] = 42
```